# Vim Vertical Split Highlight Not Turning Off

Tags: vim

I am having trouble on making the Vim Vertical Split Highlight disappear permanently.

When I use this command in Vim command line `:hi VertSplit ctermbg=None` the vertical split highlight disappears (as seen in Screen 'B'), but when I use the same command in the .vimrc.after (I am using janus for vim, as seen in screen 'A') [image: Screenshot of my Vim VerticalSplit state] the command does not work. I have tried many variations of the command with 'let','set', etc but no result, the Vertical Split stays.

Can someone please help and let me know what I doing wrong or what I am suppose to do? I want to remove the VerticalSplit highlight from my Vim.

Comment: did you put the command at the end of your vimrc? some plugin/script may change the hi as well, and it could be "lazy loaded", you can check when and where it was set by `:verbose hi VertSplit`

Comment: Wow!! thanks a ton.. putting it in the last worked.. Yes I think it was being 'lazy loaded' ..had been wrecking my brains since couple of hours now.. thanks again :)

Comment: don't use any well configured vim distribution.

Comment: Sorry didn't understand your last statement, especially 'well configured' distribution ... and also I noticed the vertical split highlight comes back when I use other color schemes even though its turned off in the .vimrc .. I guess I will have to edit the individual color schemes :(

Answer (score 2):

Your  *.vimrc* is  executed sequentially,  so probably  this command  is
being  executed  but then  having  its  changes overwritten  by  another
command  or plugin  of yours.  The solution  would then  be to  move the
command to after  these other changes happen. This may  and may not work
depending on your  setup (check `:h startup` for a  list of what happens
at startup and in what order).

The best solution  in my opinion is  to use an auto  command. These will
execute  a command  after  an  event, for  example  startup finished  or
colorscheme changed. Add this to your *.vimrc*:

```
autocmd! ColorScheme * hi VertSplit ctermbg=none
```

Now, whenever the colorscheme is  changed, this command will trigger for
any file  (`*`). This will trigger  as well by your  initial colorscheme
set in your *.vimrc*.

**Important!** If your  colorscheme set in your *.vimrc*  is done before
your `autocmd` line, then of course  nothing will be triggered (it won't
be capturing the event yet). In this case you have two options: first is
to obviously  move the  colorscheme set to  after the  `autocmd`. Second
option is add an additional event listener by changing the line to:

```
autocmd! VimEnter,ColorScheme * hi VertSplit ctermbg=none
```

Now this will  be triggered both after Vim's startup  process (after all
*.vimrc* stuff  is done and  loaded) and  also whenever you  change your
colorscheme. This way, you don't  need to change your colorscheme files.
And you should never have to do that anyway. The point of *.vimrc* is to
keep  all your  configuration  in one  file. So  this  editor of  course
provides options to make this happen.

Comment: BTW this second option, with `VimEnter`, is what I'd use because my _.vimrc_ is organized in a way that it has all auto commands grouped and they sit after the graphic config stuff. And I wouldn't change that order! :D

Comment: The problem persists even after I put the `autocmd! VimEnter,ColorScheme * hi VertSplit ctermgb=none` ... is it possible for you to share your vimrc file?

Comment: @Shahsayyad sorry, I just spotted a typo (`ctermgb`). Could that be the problem? Please try it out, and reload your vimrc / Vim

Comment: Hi @sidyll I had already tried that with `ctermbg` but still the result was not there ... any way thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Shahsayyad Sorry that I keep bothering you with this, but I'd love to see it solved! So, first, i used `none` instead of `None` because that made sense to me, but if the capitalized worked for you then you should try that as well. Another option is to use `ctermbg=bg`. I used `guibg=bg` for instance. There is nothing wrong with the command, apparently, unless I'm missing something important. Please try it directly into command mode as well, instead of .vimrc. It is also possible that some of your plugins are removing this auto command. Go step by step.

Comment: @Shahsayyad if `:hi VertSplit ctermbg=None` works, then try `:au ColorScheme * hi VertSplit ctermbg=None` first, in command mode. If that works, add it to your vimrc. If it breaks, there is something happening with your "distribution". That's what Kent meant above. Don't use already configured vim "distributions" if you don't want hard to track problems...

Comment: thanks for your help ... i am really glad that you are helping me on this ... but unfortunately its not working ... i tried `:au ColorScheme * hi VertSplit ctermbg=None` in command mode with capital `None` and small `none` but its not helping ... yes now I understand what @kent meant ...

Comment: @Shahsayyad please init vim with `vim -u NONE`. This will skip any initializations, .vimrc, etc. Now do the autocmd (`:au ColorScheme * hi VertSplit ctermbg=bg` or `ctermbg=none` or whatever worked when you did `:hi` outside a autocmd) and set a color scheme (`:color <name>`). The autocmd must be triggered when you set the color scheme. And if it does, it is certain that anything else is interfering with your autocmds, either your plugins or vimrc for example.

Comment: Oh! in compatible mode i am not able to open Nerdtree and thus cant view the vertical split ...  I did load more files in the vertical split mode (without the file explorer) so i had two views and the vertical split was highlighted with the background ... I tried the command and its various variations but the VertSplit background didn't disappear.

Comment: @Shahsayyad I'm sorry, I'm running a bit out of options. If you initialize with `vim -u NONE` and try `:hi VertSplit ctermbg=bg` does that work? I mean, outside the autocmd. Because if it does work and the command does not, then I don't know..Maybe other experts here will have the knowledge to solve it.

Comment: Thank you very much @sidyll ... really appreciate your help